# Javascript : Sum into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, sum

My function is :

```
var myArray = new Array();
$('input:checked').each(function(index) {
    myArray .push($(this).attr('id') + " : " +$(this).val());
});
```

Let me know how to sum in this array :

```
myArray [ "Apple: 10", "Apple: 3", "Banana: 3", "Pear: 7", "Pineapple: 7" ]
```

My result >

```
myNewArray [ "Apple: 13",  "Banana: 3", "Pear: 7", "Pineapple: 7" ]
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code.

Comment: Well, a way to sum the array would be to replace the string `"Apple: 10", "Apple: 3"` with the string `"Apple: 10", "Apple: 3"`.

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs??? Fix that!

Comment: There are several conceptual and approach errors here...

Comment: You need to take a look at the types of JS objects you're using to store your data. Arrays are really inappropriate here. Objects would be much better. (what @Masiorama said, in other words).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an XY question, coming from a situation which shouldn't exist (duplicate ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an object version. This is not really what you're after, but along the same lines and honestly, a bit neater as it's a data structure.

```js
var myArray = [ "Apple: 10", "Apple: 3", "Banana: 3", "Pear: 7", "Pineapple: 7" ];
var newArray = {};

myArray.forEach(function(val) {
  var item =  val.split(":");
  var key = item[0];
  var num = parseInt(item[1], 10);

  if ( newArray.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
    newArray[key] += num;
  } else {
    newArray[key] = num;
  }

});

alert ( JSON.stringify(newArray) );
```

And, as said in the comments, when we look at:

```
myArray .push($(this).attr('id') + " : " +$(this).val());
```

And

```
myArray [ "Apple: 10", "Apple: 3", "Banana: 3", "Pear: 7", "Pineapple: 7" ]
```

You seem to have duplicate IDs in your document which needs to be fixed first as an ID must be unique in any given document.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to split up the array elements an add them to a temporary object:

```
var regex = /([A-Za-z]+): (\d+)/
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  var match = arr[i].match(regex);
  var name = match[1];
  var value = match[2];
  if (!obj[name]) obj[name] = 0;
  obj[name] += +value;
}
```

This will leave you with an object that looks like:

```
console.log(obj) // { Apple: 13, Banana: 3, Pear: 7, Pineapple: 7 }
```

Personally I would leave it like this as objects are really easy to manipulate.

However, if you really need the data back in an array again, just loop over the object and push strings as elements into an array:

```
var out = [];
for (var p in obj) {
    out.push(p + ': ' + obj[p]);
}

console.log(out) // [ "Apple: 13", "Banana: 3", "Pear: 7", "Pineapple: 7" ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4sbwq64m/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.

```js
var data =  [ "Apple: 10", "Apple: 3", "Banana: 3", "Pear: 7", "Pineapple: 7" ];
var newObject = {};
var sum = 0;
$.each(data,function(k,v){
  var key = v.split(":")[0];
  var value = v.split(":")[1];
  if((key in newObject))
  {
    newObject[key] = parseInt(newObject[key]) + parseInt(value);
  }
  else
  {
    newObject[key] = $.trim(value);
  }
  
});
console.log(newObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't even do what the asker wants it to do

Comment: OP wants the sum of values in array, now OP has changes code.

Comment: The example was there since the first revision

Comment: Calling an object `newArray` is kinda confusing

Comment: @JanDvorak, now is it fine?

Answer (score -2):

Previous answer was wrong. 
I have fixed, sorry

```
var myArray = [ "Apple: 10", "Apple: 3", "Banana: 3", "Pear: 7", "Pineapple: 7" ],
newArray= {},
i,
temp;
for (i=0; i<myArray.length;i++){
     temp = myArray[i].split(':');
     temp[0] = temp[0].replace( /\s/g, "");
     temp[1] = temp[1].replace( /\s/g, "");
    if(newArray[temp[0]]){
         newArray[temp[0]] = newArray[temp[0]] + parseInt(temp[1]);
    }else{
          newArray[temp[0]] = parseInt(temp[1]);
    }
 }
 console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Do you think that would return what OP asks for ?